# jsPDF addHTML() only working for document.body

Tags: meteor, pdf-generation, jspdf, html2canvas

I am attempting to create a pdf of a page from my meteor powered site.  The page contains quite a bit of styling and some d3 charts.
I have added `chipcastledotcom:jspdf` and `new3rs:html2canvas` to accomplish my goal.  My plan is to use jsPDF's .addHTML() function to add the non chart html to the pdf.  My issue is that unless I pass in document.body as the source for `.addHTML()` the rendered element is blacked out in the pdf.  Using document.body I am able to see the currently viewable material on the webpage but nothing else (the page has quite a bit of content and requires scrolling).  Is there some lack of support in jsPDF for certain levels of complexity w.r.t. to the webpage layout/styling?

More importantly, is there a fix/work-around for this?

Here is a jsfiddle (works perfectly) that demonstrates what I'm trying to accomplish: https://jsfiddle.net/jdcast/tqfdkusp/.

To be clear, the `.addHTML()` in the fiddle works well:

```
 doc.addHTML(document.getElementById('div1'), 0, 0, function() {
   console.log('callback');
   doc.save('sampler-file.pdf');
 });
```

However, in my site's code which is verbatim what is in the fiddle, I have to use the following to see any output that ISN'T blacked out:

```
doc.addHTML(document.body, 0, 0, function() {
  console.log('callback');
  doc.save('sampler-file.pdf');
});
```

Note also that I have used jsPDF's .text() function and it seems to behave properly so I don't think I have installed it incorrectly.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey mate, i found demo for this, so here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/xzZ7n/4861/